# Ruby -- Get User Input outside of the Command Line using Ocra

Tags: ruby, user-input, ocra

So I have a very simple single file script:

```
puts "Enter the file name"
file = gets.chomp
puts "What do you want to replace it with?"
replace = gets.chomp
```

which then changes some files with the user-inputs. I packaged it up with Ocra, but I was hoping it would open up the command line when it was run and ask for the user inputs or something, or a pop-up window maybe. I need this to be very simple since my users won't know to go to the command line and run the .exe from there with arguments, so is there a way to to get a window to pop-up that takes in user input every time the .exe file is run? I've tried it in both .rb and .rbw formats.

Answer (score 0):

`cmd` (or maybe it's cmd.exe) should work on Windows. It shells out to the cmd command which should launch a cmd window.

Comment: Hmmm I entered system("start cmd.exe") before everything, but all it does is open the command line without prompting for user-input. Should I be doing it some other way?

Comment: Oh yeah, you want to tell cmd to run a program. So you could have a something.rb file which asks the user for input and then echoes what the user types in so that it can be read by the main program.